# @variables in FreeTDS

Tags: sql-server, linux, freetds

I am attempting a quick prototype-port of some old database code over to use the FreeTDS library. Currently, I am looking at a query similar to

```
SELECT x,y,z from MyTable WHERE id = @arg1
```

When I execute the query, I naturally get an error like `Must declare the scalar variable "@arg1".`

But one thing eludes me. How do I declare this variable? I have looked through the [API docs and code examples](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa936985%28v=sql.80%29) over and over again and I can't seem to find how to solve this should-be-trivial task.

The code I currently use is:

```
if(dbcmd(proc, "SELECT x,y,z from MyTable WHERE id = @arg1") != SUCCEED) {
  return fail("Failed to dbcmd()"); 
}

if(dbsqlexec(proc) != SUCCEED) {
  return fail("Failed to dbsqlexec()");
}

while((retcode=dbresults(proc)) == SUCCEED) {
  while(dbnextrow(proc) != NO_MORE_ROWS) {
    int len = dbdatlen(proc, 1);
    char* data = (char*)dbdata(proc, 1);
    cout << string(data, len) << endl;
  }
}
```

Comment: Can you show the code where you build and execute your query? FreeTDS is a low-level protocol, not an ORM or query tool so you usually need to consult Microsoft's [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187953(v=sql.105).aspx) in case of syntax issues.

Comment: Example code added. Yes, I know that FreeTDS is low level. I am trying to integrate MSSQL with a legacy C++ app, so it actually suits me quite well in this case, if I can just get my head around the details...

Comment: You can try either "DECLARE @MyVariable int" or "@arg1", OleDbType.Integer" to add as dbcmd(dbproc, "_HERE_" ); after your dbcmd(proc,"SELECT .....");

Comment: @AvkashChauhan This is basically what I currently do. I was, however, expecting a binary API for setting the variables, but the method you describe works. If there is no better way, I will accept that as an answer :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try either "DECLARE @MyVariable int" or "@arg1", OleDbType.Integer" to add as dbcmd(dbproc, "HERE" ); after your dbcmd(proc,"SELECT .....");

```
dbcmd(dbproc,"SELECT x,y,z from MyTable WHERE id = @arg1");
dbcmd(dbproc, "DECLARE @arg1 int" );
```

I do'nt think if there is any API however I am sure this is the way you could use it.

Comment: Did not find an API for it, so I settled with using DECLARE for now.